# How to achieve a ff ligature with a smaller first f "on the back of" the second

Tags: ligatures

I am laying out a third party text that requires a ff ligature with the first f slightly smaller and "on the back of" the second f.

How can I achieve this in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Has your 3rd party identified a suitable font?

Comment: I am free to choose any font I like. I guess this is in fact not a LaTeX question. Should I remove it?

Comment: how did you generate the image you show? if it was from a pdf or similar you can extract the font information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several fonts from the standard installation have these ligatures. Here are a few. I'm sure this list is incomplete. Your example looks like it might be Cochineal.

```
\usepackage{cochineal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

[image]

```
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

[image]

```
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

[image]

```
\usepackage{gfsdidot}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

[image]

```
\usepackage{kmath,kerkis} % The order of the packages matters; kmath changes the default text font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ligatures are a font feature: you will need to use a font the look of which you like supporting the required ligatures. (ff is a very common one, though.)